# MSSQL hook for the Airflow

Tags: hook, airflow, pymssql

I am trying to connect to the Mssql Server using Airflow Hooks but throwing me the error of:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/odoo_customer_sql.py] No module named 'pymssql'
```

My code is:

```
hook = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id='ofo_sql_server')
conn = hook.get_conn()
return conn
```

P.S: I am using Docker Container which includes:

```
 webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1
    build:
      context: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow.git#1.10.1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        AIRFLOW_DEPS: gcp_api,s3, mssql, pyodbc
        PYTHON_DEPS: sqlalchemy==1.2.0, pyodbc == 4.0.27, pymssql == 2.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open docker dashboard
- Open apache airflow CLI (command line interface)
- `pip install pymssql --upgrade`
- Restart the web server
- Refresh the browser

This should resolve the issue.